Are there q-analogs of GKZ (Gelfand-Kapranov-Zelevinsky) hypergeometric differential equations?
GKZ (Gelfand-Kapranov-Zelevinsky) hypergeometric differential equations are generalisations of standard hypergeometric equations/functions and  important for example for mirror symmetry. It is system of multi-variable equations (for functions of many variables).
For the (generalized) hypergeometric function/equation - there is well developed theory of q-analogs:   basic hypergeometric series. Differential equations are substituted by q-difference equations (examples).
Question: Are there q-analogs for GKZ equations/functions ?
Googling have not lead  me to the answers.
